# Child views inside MaterialCardView shrinking and vanishing

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-cardview

`android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView` has been used in native `axml` layout and have child view as below , my goal is keep switching border i.e stroke when some event occurs ,ex: button click and revert it , but the every change in `strokeWidth` the child views shrinka bit gradually and finally width and height become 0 making inner view completely vanish.

MaterialCardView layout code:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView  
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_margin="10dp"
              app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
              app:strokeColor="#123456"
              app:strokeWidth="3dp"
              android:id="@+id/material_card"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
              <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                              android:layout_height="240dp"
                              android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutCard">
                <Button android:id="@+id/button"
                        android:text="Click me"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textview"
                          android:text ="Border in"
                          android:layout_below="@id/button"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**PageRenderer code**

---

```
  public void OnClick(Android.Views.View v)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
            if (_yes)
            {
                material_card.StrokeColor = Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#FFFFFF");
                material_card.StrokeWidth = 0;
                //material_card.LayoutParameters.LayoutAnimationParameters
                linearLayoutCard?.SetMinimumHeight(material_card.Height+20);
                linearLayoutCard?.SetMinimumWidth(material_card.Width+20);
                linearLayoutCard.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                textview.Text = "Border out";
                _yes = false;
               // return true;
            }
            else
            {
                material_card.StrokeColor = Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#123456");
                material_card.StrokeWidth = 20;
                linearLayoutCard?.SetMinimumHeight(material_card.Height);
                linearLayoutCard?.SetMinimumWidth(material_card.Width);
                linearLayoutCard.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                textview.Text = "Border in";
                _yes = true;
                //return true;
            }
        }
```

**After few clicks:**

[image: Issue_image]

I tried to use other layout `RelativeLayout` which dint work and also tried to increase the LinearLayout height and width and set padding to 0 to min as in the above , that also not working,while debugging I noticed Padding gets triggered for `MaterialCardView` and that probably causing it shrink it down.
Also tried setting padding of cardview to 0 but still no luck.

```
material_card.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
linearLayoutCard.LayoutParameters.Width = material_card.Width;
linearLayoutCard.LayoutParameters.Height =material_card.Height;
```

Why inner views are not set with higher width since its mapped to `match_parent` /`fill_parent` ?

Full Code at Github : [github.com/pmahend1/TestMaterialCardView](https://github.com/pmahend1/TestMaterialCardView)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve

Comment: @G.hakim my goal is keep switching border i.e stroke when some event occurs ,ex: button click and revert it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with this class that is causing its content padding into keeping increasing after changing the `StrokeWidth` values.

Try resetting the *ContentPadding* every time you set the `StrokeWith` to *0* with this line of code:

`material_card.SetContentPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Wasted so much time on this, I reverted to using normal `CardView` and switching `background` of `stroke` I dint know there was `SetContentPadding` for `CardView` Thanks!